# WKWebView programmatically reload trigger didFailProvisionalNavigation

Tags: ios, wkwebview

A `UISplitViewController` base App, master is `UITableViewController`, detail is `UIViewController`.

When `UITableViewController` cell taps, `NSNotificationCenter` post a `notification`, reload the `WKWebView` in `detailViewController`.

Reload successlly, but always trigger WKNavigationDelegate        [webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:], why????

MasterViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:aNotification
                                                       object:nil];
    });
}
```

DetailViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(__shouldReload:) name:aNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)__shouldReload:(NSNotification *)sender
{
    [_webView reload];
}
```

Comment: Nslog the error and check what it says?

Comment: The error code:

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x7ff5cb4823c0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.google.com.tw, _WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=<WKReloadFrameErrorRecoveryAttempter: 0x7ff5cb492220>, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.google.com.tw}

Comment: i think your webview is loading 2 times..
This error may occur if an another request is made before the previous request of WebView is completed...

Comment: Thanks for @aBilal17
Yes. It's loading twice, I found there is another Notification trigger the method.

Comment: @ShinrenPan can you share what you found

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by "App Transport Security". You can either use HTTPS or you can set an exception in your Info.plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
<dict>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    <true/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
</dict>
```

What the WWDC video [Networking with NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-711/)

[What's New in iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html)

> App Transport Security
>
> App Transport Security (ATS) enforces best practices in the secure connections between an app and its back end. ATS prevents accidental disclosure, provides secure default behavior, and is easy to adopt; it is also on by default in iOS 9 and OS X v10.11. You should adopt ATS as soon as possible, regardless of whether you’re creating a new app or updating an existing one.
>
> If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS as much as you can right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as soon as possible. In addition, your communication through higher-level APIs needs to be encrypted using TLS version 1.2 with forward secrecy. If you try to make a connection that doesn't follow this requirement, an error is thrown. If your app needs to make a request to an insecure domain, you have to specify this domain in your app's Info.plist file.